# Problems passing params when creating a model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Product.rb model in my Rails app, and it has a :title attribute and a :price attribute. From the Rails console I can successfully create an instance of one of these models, but I'm having trouble passing values for the :title and :price. Here's my products_controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

def create

@product = Product.create(
  :name = params[:name],
  :price = params[:price]
  )
end

end
```

This is the command I use to create an instance:

```
Product.create("name", 123)
```

The :name attribute is set to be text and the :price attribute to be an integer. But when I hit enter this is what I got:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
```

I haven't written any Rails since before v4 and I'm a bit rusty. Anyone know the problem?

Comment: It should be `:name => params[:name]` etc, arrow, not assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `>` in your hash rockets.

Try this:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @product = Product.create(
      :name => params[:name],
      :price => params[:price]
    )
  end
end
```

Incidentally, unless you're doing something particularly special, it looks like you're probably doing the form in a non-conventional way.

You should be using a form helper along these lines in your view:

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  ...
```

And then in your controller, creating the product as follows:

```
def create
  @product = Product.new(params[:product])

  if @product.save
    ...
end
```

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by @Iceman, if you're using Rails 4 you'll need to use Strong Parameters for the params used for mass-assignment.

Typically you'd create a private method to handle these, and call that within your object creation/update method calls:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    if @product.save
      ...
  end

  private

  def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price)
  end
end
```

Comment: You'll need strong_parameters if this is Rails 4.